# Problem in defining the Inductive effect

Tags: organic-chemistry, inductive-effect

Inductive effect is introduced in many textbooks by giving an example of an alkyl halide $R-X$.

The bond **C1-X** is polar due to electronegativity difference, therefore **X** gains partial negative charge ∆(-), and **C1** gains partial positive ∆(+). Due to some deficiency of electrons in the **C1** , **C2-C1** bond becomes polar and above process is repeated.

So by this point of view, if we take $R-Li$, as **C1-Li** bond is polar, **Li** gains ∆(+) and **C** gains ∆(-) and above thinking process is repeated again.

Thus we can conclude that Carbon chain can act as both +I and -I depending upon the situation on hand.

> So why do we always consider an alkyl chain to be a +I group?

Example, if on a carbon chain, there is a carbanion, we still consider alkyl group to be +I, but it should have been the opposite.

Comment: This is going to be a redundant question...I thought this confusion would be finally answered :(

Comment: Well, is the $C-Li$ bond an organic bond?

Comment: @Firefox1921, what do you mean by 'organic bond'?

Comment: Also if you aren't satisfied with C-Li, we can take C-B (boron) as well, or even a carbanion attached to alkyl group.

Comment: I think that inductive effect is a relative concept, it depends on the type of substituents attached to the carbon chain. As Li is more electropositive compared to C or C is more electronegative with respect to Li. So, R group shows -I effect and Li shows +I effect.

Comment: I agree with @Manu here. A classic example is the Grignard Reagent. The $R$ group in the Grignard Reagent is a $-I$ group, while the Mg gains a partial positive sign.

Comment: @B.Anshuman What I meant is, that kind of bond is called an *organo-metallic* bond, it's not an ordinary $\ce{C-H}$ or a $\ce{C=O}$ bond that is usually found. The organo-metallic bond is also found in coordination complexes, so you have to look at them more carefully, as they maybe different in the way that they behave than, say a regular $\ce{-C-X}$ bond.

Comment: @Manu, your statement is what I have written as argument against the defining example of inductive effect.

Comment: @Firefox1921, I agree that bond nature might differ but it is still a majorly covalent bond in the case of R-CuLi. I am saying so because R has ∆(-) on it unlike the Grignard reagent or R-Li.

Comment: So, what are you trying to say @B.Anshuman. I'm sorry but I'm unable to understand what is the point you're making.

Comment: @Firefox1921, Manu has pretty much summarised what I said.

Comment: Further I am asking is that in many textbooks, R is always considered a +I group regardless of the substituent. Even though the substituent is a carbanion.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/109640/discussion-between-firefox1921-and-b-anshuman).

Comment: @Firefox1921, what do you conclude?